# asp.net web.api 2 "defaults" to WindowsIdentity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, claims-based-identity, claims

I'm trying to build a custom middleware to authenticatate user by cookies with a claim based approach.
In the process i discovered that the default identity is WindowsIdentiy, and not ClaimsIdentity as i would expect.

The application is hosted on local IIS, with "Anonymous Authentication" enabled, and "Windows Authentication" disabled.

So i really have no idea why this is a windowsidentity.

[image]

To make the WindowsIdentity go away, i tried following:

Added authorization to web.config to force Anonymous Authentication:

```
<authorization>
      <allow users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

Added to WebApiConfig.cs Register method to suppress authentication setting on IIS:

```
config.SuppressHostPrincipal();
```

But still the WindowsIdentity showed up.

Can anyone point me in direction on how to acheive a claim based solution?

Complete code:

Startup.cs

```
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(ThgCatalogApi.Startup))]

namespace ThgCatalogApi
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            //app.UseOwinExceptionHandler();            
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.Auth.cs

```
using ThgCatalogApi.Security;
using Owin;

namespace ThgCatalogApi
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            app.Use(typeof(ApiCookieAuthMiddleware));
        }
    }
}
```

ApiCookieAuthMiddleware.cs

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;

namespace ThgCatalogApi.Security
{
    public class ApiCookieAuthMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
    {
        public ApiCookieAuthMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
        {

        }

        public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
        {
            var user = context.Authentication.User;
        }
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ThgCatalogApi
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.SuppressHostPrincipal();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you disabled Windows Authentication on the IIS server level or site level?

Comment: Yes, both site level and server level is disabled, and Anonymous Authentication is enabled on both levels.

Comment: i have the same issue. in my case i have custom authentication attributes which all create an instance of my own custom principle if authenticated. Most of the time it works and the authenticated user has the right type of principal, but on two random occasions it has been WindowsIdentity. As above I have windows authentication disabled in IIS so cant understand why it would ever be this type of principal

Comment: I actually never figured out what was causing the problem. But i moved my authentication to a custom attribute instead of using my own middleware. When doing so everything works like a charm.